# How to move tooltip on mouse move?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm only able to hover the tooltip but the tooltip doesn't move on mouse move.

```js
const tooltip = document.querySelector('.toolhere + section');
window.onmousemove = function(e) {
  const x = (e.clientX + 3) + 'px',
    y = (e.clientY + 3) + 'px';
  for (var i = 0; i < tooltip.length; i++) {
    tooltip[i].style.top = y;
    tooltip[i].style.left = x;
  }
};
```

```css
.toolhere {
  position: relative;
}

.toolhere+section {
  display: none !important;
  background-color: #ECECEC;
  color: #4D4E53;
  padding: 4px 8px 4px 9px;
  font-size: 12px;
}

.toolhere:hover+section {
  display: block !important;
  position: fixed;
}
```

```html
<div class="items">
  <div class="sub-content">
    <div class="iconsize toolhere">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100.jpg" />
    </div>
    <section class="tooltip">this is tooltip</section>
  </div>
  <div class="sub-content">
    <div class="content-name toolhere"></div>
    <section class="tooltip">this is tooltip</section>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: replace `querySelector` with `querySelectorAll` and it will work

Comment: Can I use mouse move function twice ?, Because I faced issue it was not working for twice that'll be working for only for the first time used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've used `querySelector()` method to access the DOM element. This method is used to access single element.

`querySelectorAll()` method is used to access all elements which matches the CSS query. `querySelectorAll()` method returns a **NodeList**.

In this Snippet below `forEach` loop is used.
Since NodeList selected by `querySelectorAll()` has an *array-like* structure so you can directly apply **forEach** method with it and pass element as the first element in the callback function

```js
let tooltips = document.querySelectorAll('.toolhere + section');

document.addEventListener("mousemove", function(e) {
  const posX = `${e.clientX + 3}px`;
  const posY = `${e.clientY + 3}px`;

   tooltips.forEach((tooltip) => {
    tooltip.style.top = posY;
    tooltip.style.left = posX;
  });
});
```

```css
.toolhere {
  position: relative;
}

.toolhere+section {
  opacity: 0;
  width: fit-content;
  position: fixed;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  background-color: #ECECEC;
  color: #4D4E53;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 4px 8px 4px 9px;
  font-size: 12px;
  transition: opacity .5s;
}

.toolhere:hover+section {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="items">
  <div class="sub-content">
    <div class="iconsize toolhere">
      <img src="https://media.istockphoto.com/photos/positive-man-celebrating-success-picture-id1221837116?k=20&m=1221837116&s=612x612&w=0&h=HfTeaCWySduic6zF3kC-jGjWq_JgQUc5BtBjdCzBQzU=" />
    </div>
    <section class="tooltip">this is tooltip</section>
  </div>
  <div class="sub-content">
    <div class="content-name toolhere"></div>
    <section class="tooltip">this is tooltip</section>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: can I use the same for multiple HTML CSS files???

Comment: I mean same function repeat twice is possible with same JS file???

Comment: Which function you want repeat twice?

Comment: Function can be repeated twice . . .

Comment: But it is not working in repeation..

Comment: What do you want to repeat? Clear that point first . . .

Comment: The Javascript function

Comment: Is that `mousemove` function?

Answer (score 0):

The return value of `querySelector` is not an array,
cannot be traversed

Please use `querySelectorAll` instead

```js
const tooltip = document.querySelectorAll('.toolhere + section');
window.onmousemove = function(e) {
  const x = (e.clientX + 3) + 'px',
    y = (e.clientY + 3) + 'px';
  for (var i = 0; i < tooltip.length; i++) {
    tooltip[i].style.top = y;
    tooltip[i].style.left = x;
  }
};
```

```css
.toolhere {
  position: relative;
}

.toolhere+section {
  display: none !important;
  background-color: #ECECEC;
  color: #4D4E53;
  padding: 4px 8px 4px 9px;
  font-size: 12px;
}

.toolhere:hover+section {
  display: block !important;
  position: fixed;
}
```

```html
<div class="items">
  <div class="sub-content">
    <div class="iconsize toolhere">
      <img src="pic.png"/>
    </div>
    <section class="tooltip">this is tooltip</section>
  </div>
  <div class="sub-content">
    <div class="content-name toolhere"></div>
    <section class="tooltip">this is tooltip</section>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Oops its working thank you so much. I'm happy with the output. :)))

Comment: Can I use mouse move function twice ?, Because I faced issue it was not working for twice that'll be working for only for the first time used.

Comment: @ManjunathL Do you mean to use this function for another tooltip? or something else?

Comment: Yup, but I found solution for that instead of using window.onmouseover twice I can use document.onmouseover. It works..